# DataGridView in winforms

Tags: c#, datagridview

when i click on a datagridview, it makes a table to show an object(default constructor of my class) that appears, but i don't make it by myself. i use a bindinglist and dk how to fix the problem

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public BindingList Automobiles = new BindingList();

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = Automobiles;
    }

    private void newFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Automobiles.Count > 0)
        { Automobiles.Clear(); }
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form  = new Form2(this);
        form.Show();
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        
    }

    private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt|All Files|*.*"; // Specify the file types you want to allow

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

                try
                {
                    // Read the contents of the selected file
                    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

                    foreach (string line in lines)
                    {
                        // Parse each line to create 'auto' objects
                        string[] parts = line.Split(','); // Assuming the data is comma-separated
                        if (parts.Length == 6)
                        {
                            if (Enum.TryParse(parts[0], out brand brand) &&
                                int.TryParse(parts[3], out int power) &&
                                double.TryParse(parts[4], out double fuel_cons) &&
                                double.TryParse(parts[5], out double tank_capacity))
                            {
                                type type;
                                Enum.TryParse(parts[2], out type);

                                auto newAuto = new auto(brand, parts[1], type, power, fuel_cons, tank_capacity);
                                Automobiles.Add(newAuto);  
                                //dataGridView1.Add(newAuto)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Refresh the DataGridView to display the updated data
                    //dataGridView1.Refresh();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error reading the file: " + ex.Message, "Error");
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

}[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuSQ4.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veDam.png)

Comment: The grid will generate columns according whats it gets bound to in your case instances of your "auto" class. If you don't want that create the columns manually and bind them to the fitting properties of your auto class.

Comment: Welcome @Roman... Please see: [Why should I not upload images of code data errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)